# AJAX and JQuery to get data from XML response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

Here is my url: http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=20

if you plug that into a browser you will see the xml it returns.

I am trying to use the following code to get the url for the jpg file and display them on my page but I keep getting an error.  btn4 is a button on the page and all that works:

```
    $(".btn4").click(function () {
    "use strict";
    ajaxDemo1();
});
```

Here is the function called and the ajax code inside that triggers the alert indicating an error.  Your help is appreciated.

```
    function ajaxDemo1() {

    "use strict";

    var i = 0, url1;

    $(".cute-images").html("Loading...");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=20",
        timeout: 2000,
        success: function (xml) {
            //$(".cute-images").html("");
            $(xml).find("image").each(function () {
                var url1 = "<img src='" + $(this).find("url").text() + "'/>";
                $(".cute-images").append(url1);
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
            if (textStatus === "timeout")
                $(".cute-images").html("Request timed out, server may be busy, try again later.");
            else if (textStatus === "error")
                $(".cute-images").html(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

There is something else I don't understand that may be a clue?  After the $.ajax block but still inside the function I try to display a specific url image from the, I get the image to display and then it disappears like it is being refreshed or cleared out???  But I can display that image url in a separate browser tab and it stays there.

HTML is simple:

```
<div class="cute-images"><h2></h2></div>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaykum/4uu8psy0/

Comment: Your code should work. Unfortunately I cant see XML looping in fiddle because of cross-domain issues. Do you get any errors in console? If you output `xml` in in `success` to console, what do you get? --- `console.log(xml)`

Comment: same as @Zealander, only thing I can see wrong is the cross-domain issue. Are you getting that error in the developer console?

Comment: I see this error in the console that I did not notice before:

SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:50630 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

I am doing something similar with a reddit request and getting a json response and successfully using that.

Comment: @jaykum I don't know much about The Cat API, but it looks like it does not allow cross-domain requests. I see people complaining about this in the comments here: http://thecatapi.com/docs.html#comment-2220711075   You probably need to get the API key from them and call it with the key to bypass CORS.

Comment: I was able to get my code to work using Bing Search.  Most of the other APIs are very spotty in response.